# Using Or and Select in a Where clause to compare all entries with an int, with lambda expressions

Tags: c#, linq, select, lambda, where-clause

I have to make this method `GetByNameOrAwardYearOrderedByAwardYearDesc` to display all Laureates with the correct name or all Laureates within that year and I've gotten pretty close but I'm getting an error

> operator == cannot be applied to operands of type `IEnumerable<int>` and `int`

I understand the error, but I don't know how to properly solve it. I've been trying a lot of things and searching online too, but I can't find any examples like this.

```
public ICollection<Laureate> GetByNameOrAwardYearOrderedByAwardYearDesc(string name, int year)
{
    List<Laureate> laureatesList = _dbContext.Laureates
                                             .Include(p => p.Prizes)
                                             .Where(p => p.Name == name || p.Prizes.Select(ay => ay.AwardYear) == year)
                                             // .Where(p => p.Name == name || p.Prizes.Select(ay => ay.AwardYear == year)
                                             // .Where(p => p.Name == name || p.Prizes.AwardYear == year)
                                            .Select(p => new Laureate
                                                         {
                                                             Id = p.Id,
                                                             Name = p.Name,
                                                             FamilyName = p.FamilyName,
                                                             BirthDate = p.BirthDate,
                                                             Prizes = p.Prizes
                                                         }) 
                                            .ToList();

    return laureatesList; 
}

public class Laureate
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string FamilyName { get; set; }
    public DateTime? BirthDate { get; set; }
    public List<Prize> Prizes { get; set; }
}

public class Prize
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int AwardYear { get; set; }
    public int CategoryId { get; set; }
    public virtual Category Category { get; set; }
    public DateTime? DateAwarded { get; set; }
    public PrizeStatus Status { get; set; }
    public String Motivation { get; set; }
    public decimal Amount { get; set; }
    public int LaureateId { get; set; }
    public virtual Laureate Owner { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try to update your `Where` clause by adding [`Any`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.any?view=netframework-4.8#System_Linq_Enumerable_Any__1_System_Collections_Generic_IEnumerable___0__System_Func___0_System_Boolean__) method

```cs
.Where(p => p.Name == name || p.Prizes.Any(ay => ay.AwardYear == year))
.Select(...)
//rest of code
```

Since you want to find

> all Laureates within that year

`Any` method checks whether any element of a sequence satisfies a condition, in your case you are checking that any prize of given `Laureate` was awarded during a given year

Comment: Thank you! I didn't know about .Any but it works!

For anyone else who might come acress this, I also had to add another ) at the end.